# Error: [SlickGrid DataView] Each data element must implement a unique 'id' property

Tags: slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

For users who are getting the mentioned error while using angular slick-grid :
Angular slick grid needs a column named 'id' for each row.

Answer (score 0):

From typescript, after getting the data from the api, you can call other function which will do the following

```
addId() {
this.apiData.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.ids = index+1;
}
);
this.datasetRecords = this.apiData;
```

}

// assign the datasetRecords to the angular grid